# Delete a specific row in listbox VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I need help on my code as it can only delete a row in listbox and the sheet when it is not filtered but when it is filtered with search, it cannot delete the row.
What I want to happen is when it is filtered by searchby(user will pick a category) then input a corresponding value in searchvalue(user will input a value) then a user will pick a row then when it click the delete button, it will delete the specific row. I'm thinking if my problem really is if I did not call the sheet where it can be saved and deleted but I cannot figure it out. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Here is my code for delete button

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    
    Dim d As Integer 'test
    
    For d = 1 To Range("D500").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        If ListDatabase.Selected(d) Then
        Rows(d + 1).Select
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    Next d
Call Reset
     
    
End Sub
```

Here is my code for search button

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    If Me.txtSearchValue.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter search value.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Search"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Call SearchData
    
End Sub
```

Here's for sub searchdata

```
Sub SearchData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim shRCA As Worksheet '<-RCA sheet
    Dim shSearchData As Worksheet '<-SearchData sheet
    Dim iColumn As Integer 
    Dim iRCARow As Long
    Dim iSearchRow As Long 
    Dim sColumn As String 
    Dim sValue As String
    Set shRCA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RCA")
    Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData")
    
    iRCARow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RCA").Range("D" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    sColumn = RCAForm.cmbSearchBy.Value
    
    sValue = RCAForm.txtSearchValue.Value
    
    iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shRCA.Range("D1:U1"), 0)
    
    'Remove filter from RCA worksheet
    If shRCA.FilterMode = True Then
        shRCA.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    If RCAForm.cmbSearchBy.Value = "Case Number" Then
        shRCA.Range("D1:U" & iRCARow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue
    Else
        shRCA.Range("D1:U" & iRCARow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
    End If
    
    'If any record found
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shRCA.Range("G:G")) >= 2 Then
        
        'Code to remove the previous data from SearchData worksheet
        shSearchData.Cells.Clear
        shRCA.AutoFilter.Range.Copy shSearchData.Range("D1")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("D" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        RCAForm.ListDatabase.ColumnCount = 19
        RCAForm.ListDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30, 30, 30, 30, 50, 50, 90, 90, 90, 90, 50, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50"
        
        If iSearchRow > 1 Then
            RCAForm.ListDatabase.RowSource = "SearchData!D2:U" & iSearchRow
            MsgBox "Records Found!"
        End If
    
    Else
        MsgBox "No Record Found."
    
    End If
    
    'To remove filter from worksheet
    shRCA.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: on which sheet(s) are the data, and the Subs and SearchData()? Pause execution(insert a breakpoint) at Selection.Delete and type in the immediate window `?Activesheet.Name`. Is it the sheet where you want to delete the row?

Comment: Hello, I'm new to vba. The data that is diplayed in listbox is from Sheet13. Yes, it is also the sheet where I want to delete a row from.  I want to delete a specific row after picking from cmbSearchBy and input a value in txtSearchValue using the search button.

Comment: Try to modify  these two lines `Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("D500").End(xlUp).Row - 1` and `Worksheets("Sheet13").Rows(d + 1).Select`. With this you exactly define the sheet where selection and deletion is done.

Comment: I tried to modify the code. did I do it right? It still cannot delete when filtered with search.

'For d = 1 To Worksheets("RCA").Range("D500").End(xlUp).row - 1
        If ListDatabase.Selected(d) Then
        Worksheets("RCA").Rows(d + 1).Select
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    Next d'

Comment: Then pls. show the SearchData Sub to make clear what is filter with search.

Comment: Hello, I added the code i use for sub searchdata in my question.

Comment: Two presumes i have. 1. There is no row selected in ListDatabase when cmdDelete button clicked. 2. The selected item is under the 500th row. For this change `For d = 1 To Range("D500").End(xlUp).Row - 1` to `For d = 1 To ListDatabase.Listcount`
Sidenote: `Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"` only works as placeholder if sValue is not a `Number`, but a `String`. That is if the cells where the find is done are `Number` or `General` formatting, will not find if sValue=122 numbers as 3122 or 32122456

Comment: I encountered some errors. Select method of Range class failed in this line when I try to debug. `Worksheets("RCA").Rows(d + 1).Select`  and when I tried to delete in listbox the ones delete is the row where the current cursor in the RCA sheet not on where clicked on the listbox. Also thankyou for this criteria sidenote. for the criteria, i've changed it to where the cells looking for is a string.

Comment: Error is because `"RCA"` is not the activesheet.  You can delete the line in one step `Worksheets("RCA").Rows(d + 1).Delete`. instead of `Worksheets("RCA").Rows(d + 1).Select Selection.Delete`. But the ListBox content will not change because the source of it is on the SearchData sheet which is the copied version of the `RCA` sheet.

Comment: THankyouu now I get it that it can only delete when I'm on RCA sheet only. Also, is it a right move if I changed all searchdata to shRCA in code below?
 `shSearchData.Cells.Clear
        shRCA.AutoFilter.Range.Copy shSearchData.Range("D1")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("D" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`

Comment: This depends on the requirement. To create a copied sheet of an original, (called backup a sheet) is for manipulating data for temporary purposes, while  preserve the original ones. If you want changes made permanent either you do them directly on the original sheet, or if y use backup, after approving the result the original database must  be updated with the backup. To delete a row method (i posted in previous comment) works without selecting the sheet, means the `Delete` method works in any case.

Comment: They want to make changes in the backup then with confirmations, the original database also be updated. Thank you very much for your help on this!